# Why isn't this function inferring the type?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm using "openapi-typescript" to generate all the types from my swagger server.
Then I create a Type "GetUrls" with all the keys with "get" method

```js
import { paths } from '../types/swagger.js'

...

type GetPaths = FilterPaths<paths, 'get'>
type GetUrls = keyof GetPaths & string

...

const get = async (url: GetUrls, params: Params) => {
    //map over params
    let path = ''
    for (let param in params) {
        path = url.replace('{' + param + '}', params[param])
    }

    type Schema = GetPaths[typeof url]['get']['responses']['200']['content']['*/*']

    return (await axios.get<Schema>(path)).data
}

get('/api/user/{id}', { id: '123' }).then(data => console.log(data))
```

the autocompletion on the function "get" works flawless, but it isn't inferring the correct type

if I manually add the "url" index, it works:

```js
type Schema = GetPaths['/api/user/{id}']['get']['responses']['200']['content']['*/*']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

I added a generic that extend GetUrls

```js
get = async <T extends GetUrls & string>(url: T, params: Params, cache = false) => {
    ...
    type Schema = paths[T]['get']['responses'][200]['content']['*/*']
    return (await axios.get<Schema>(path)).data
}
```